# Vue-Routes is not functioning when a template in one of the routes is referring to the same ID

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I am developing a Vue application with Vue-routes. One of the routes has a function, that is meant to change the background colors of two divs by writing the wanted colors in re respective input fields. But there are two problems. The router is not working since I wrote this color changing function and the color change doesn't work either. So it's is basically a "fail-fail" situation. I am receiving this message from the console in Google inspection: "vue.js:597 [Vue warn]: Cannot find element: #container".

I am sure that these problems are intertwined, the question is how do I solve them?

**HTML**

```
<div id="container" v-bind:style="bga">
   <div class="top" v-bind:style="bgb">
      <div id="app">
         <h1 id="vueHead">Vue routing</h1>
         <h2 class="menu">
            <router-link to="/">Color</router-link>
            <router-link to="/main">Main</router-link>
         </h2>
      </div>
   </div>
   <!-- component matched by the route will render here -->
   <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

**index.js (routes)**

```
import MainPage from '../components/mainPage.js'
import ColorPage from '../components/colorPage.js'

var urlend;

const routes = [
    {path: '/', component: ColorPage},
    {path: '/main', component: MainPage},
    ];
const router = new VueRouter({
    routes // short for `routes: routes`
});
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#container',
    router
});
```

**colorpage.js**

```
const ColorPage = {
    template: `
<div id="middle">
    <label id="colorLabel"><h2> {{ info }} </h2></label>
    </br>
    <input type="text" class="colorInput" v-on:input="bga.backgroundColor = $event.target.value" placeholder="here...">
    </br>
    <input type="text" class="colorInput"  v-on:input="bgb.backgroundColor = $event.target.value" placeholder="... and here!">
</div>
`
};
var color = new Vue({
    el: '#container',
    data: {
        info: 'Change Colors By Typing Their Names:',
        bga: {
            backgroundColor: ''
        },
        bgb: {
            backgroundColor: ''
        }
    }
});

export default ColorPage
```

Comment: Do you have two Vue instances on purpose?

Comment: To be honest, I am still learning Vue. If I can get the wanted results while having only one instance I will do so! I am here the learn =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In colorpage.js you have new Vue(). This creates a new Vue instance. What you're likely looking for is creating a new [component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Base-Example).

For the component you don't need to define where to mount it with el, but rather Vue router takes care of it. Inside your Vue application you should define el only once and that's where the Vue instance mounts itself. After the Vue instance has mounted itself, routing happens inside Vue.